# How to switch css property according to some condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, radiobuttonlist

I have the following radiobutton list :

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_select_sign" runat="server" Visible="false" Style="text-align: right">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rb_select_sign" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="rb_select_sign_SelectedIndexChanged" CausesValidation="false"
            AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Normal</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Electronic</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:Panel>
```

---

I want to change the `css` property `overflow-y`

from   `overflow-y :auto`; to `overflow-y :hidden;`

For the div with `id = wrap_form`

if the I select the `ListItem with Value  = 1`;

---

From **FireBug** :

```
<td>
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rb_select_sign_0" type="radio" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rb_select_sign$0\',\'\')', 0)" value="0" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rb_select_sign">
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rb_select_sign_0">Normal</label>
</td>
<td>
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rb_select_sign_1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="1" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rb_select_sign">
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rb_select_sign_1">Electronic</label>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if You use the suggested javascript answers, the css will go back to normal after page postback. You already use a postback on Your `RadioButtonList`, so I suppose You can just change the style server-side instead.

**Update**

Put this in Your method handling item selection change in the list:

```
protected void rb_select_sign_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rb_select_sign.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "styleChangeScript", "<script type='text/javascript'>var divToChange = document.getElementById('wrap_form'); if(divToChange) { divToChange.style.overflowY = 'hidden' }</script>", false);
    }
    //the rest of the original code of this method should be here
    //...
}
```

To make it work when clicking other buttons etc. causing postbacks, You should place the same code lines in the `Page_Load` event of Your page (or just put it in a separate method and call it from both places).

Comment: Just let me know if the div `wrap_form` is put in the page's aspx by You or it's auto generated (and You can't see it in the aspx).

Comment: It's in the master page :

`<div id="wrap_form">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$('input[id^="ctl00_"]').click(function() {
 if ($(this).val() == 1) {
  $('#wrap_form').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
 }
})
```

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LWeD/1/)

Comment: i've made a small change, check again

Comment: Make sure You referenced jQuery library in Your page (or in the master page).

Comment: I reference that file , i think the problem is that control make a postback